# Which of Hashem's name is the name upon whom Israel is called?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shemos-sacred-names, haftarah, divine-names

We read the following (from Chabad Website) in [Divrei Hayamim II 7:14](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16556/showrashi/true#v14):

> וְיִכָּֽנְע֨וּ עַמִּ֜י אֲשֶׁ֧ר נִֽקְרָא־שְׁמִ֣י עֲלֵיהֶ֗ם וְיִֽתְפַּֽלְלוּ֙ וִֽיבַקְשׁ֣וּ פָנַ֔י וְיָשֻׁ֖בוּ מִדַּרְכֵיהֶ֣ם הָֽרָעִ֑ים וַֽאֲנִי֙ אֶשְׁמַ֣ע מִן־הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם וְאֶסְלַח֙ לְחַטָּאתָ֔ם וְאֶרְפָּ֖א אֶת־אַרְצָֽם׃
>
> And My people, upon whom My name is called, humble themselves and pray and seek My presence and repent of their evil ways, I shall hear from heaven and forgive their sin and heal their land.

My question: Which of Hashem's name is the name upon whom Israel is called? Is "Israel" also a name of Hashem?

Comment: My non-literalist understanding is that it means they are (or should be) referred to as Hashem's people, not that one of names of the people is also is also one of Hashem's names (in the way [_Shalom_ is said to be one of Hashem's names](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.10b.2?lang=bi&lang2=en)). As I have heard discussions around which exact letter was imprinted on Cain (based on [Rashi for Bereshit 4:15](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8168/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-4.htm#v15)), there probably exists an answer closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: The same phrase in Amos 9 is explained by the Malbim (when written about all other nations) as שהם יכירו שם ה' ויקבלו אמונות האמת עד שיקרא שם ה' עליהם

Comment: @YaacovDeane What are the names of those three angels, and where are they referenced? Thanks.

Comment: @rosends where can I read this, where the Malbim says this.

Comment: @ninamag https://www.sefaria.org/Amos.9.12?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en

Comment: His name "the God of Israel" afaik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yehuda/יהודה

We are called "Yehuda/Yehudim" as our eternal name and it contains the [4 letters of the] sheim Hashem in it.

The Sfas Emes explains that it's G-d's name with an added letter Daled (ד) that represents our poor state in exile. The jewish people take shelter in the name of G-d so to speak

> הִשְׁאַרְתִּ֣י בְקִרְבֵּ֔ךְ עַ֥ם עָנִ֖י וָדָ֑ל וְחָס֖וּ בְּשֵׁ֥ם יְהוָֽה׃
>
> [poor nation]...and they shall find refuge In the name of the LORD.

[See more in piece below - Sfas Emes]
(Also found here: [Sefaria - Sefat Emet](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefat_Emet%2C_Exodus%2C_For_Purim.30.4?vhe=Sefat_emet,_Piotrk%C3%B3w,_1905-1908&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Also see: [Sotah 36b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.36b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) discussing Yehudah sanctifying the name of G-d and therefore having the full name of G-d in his name.

[image: 663]

[image: Sfas Emes - Name Yehuda]

Comment: "i, what is the name, folio number, weblink, etc.., of this source?

Comment: Updated: Piece 663 on Moadim (Vol. 2) - 3rd paragraph

Comment: Hint for this: Take the bottom yud that helps form the last letter of Hashem’s Ineffable Name and transfer it up to the next letter and Hashem’s name now reads יהודי

Comment: Just curious was trying out bounty feature for the first time. Is it true that since this answer doesn't have two upvotes I don't get credit? Also just curious why this answer doesn't seem well received. Looking for feedback.

Comment: Yisrael is also our eternal name and in this verse's context wasn't it the whole nation and tribes of Yisrael?

Comment: Actually Yisrael is the more eternal name. Because Yehudi is the title of he that is Kofer against idolatry - Mordekhai haYehudi (see Likutei Moharan II:32). But in the near future b"h idolatry will be eliminated.

Comment: @Nissim: How is Yisrael the name of Hashem?

Comment: @NissimNanach I am not sure what you mean by the whole nation. Even though Yehudah is a tribe the jewish nation as a whole is referred to as "The Yehudim". It may be correct that this name is associated more with Galus (the goyim call us the Yehudim, in the Holocaust we were called 'Jude', Arabs call us 'Yahud", etc.) but it doesn't change that this is our 'name' and also it's the only name of Klal Yisrael that contains the name of Hashem in it. (If you can reverse your downvote I would appreciate it ;) )

Comment: No Yisrael isn't the name of Hashem but it's the more eternal name of our people as I've argued and supported. Also L. Moharan uses Yisrael consistently and not Yehudim. But however btw since you asked and had that impression there is a major Chaya in Shamayim called Yisrael, and there's also a Saba d'Sabin the biggest one IIRC called Yisrael Sabba -- these might be the "Supernal" analogs or angels of Lower Yisrael, I'm not expert on it but that Chaya is mentioned in the well known Braita of R' Akiba אמר רבי עקיבא חיה אחת עומדת ברקיע ושמה ישראל ...

Comment: You can be called what you want. I chose not to be called Yehudi but rather Yisrael for the reasons I said.  Od Yosef Chai  Na Nach

Answer (score 1):

The English translation of your quotation:

> וְיִכָּֽנְע֨וּ עַמִּ֜י אֲשֶׁ֧ר נִֽקְרָא־שְׁמִ֣י עֲלֵיהֶ֗ם וְיִֽתְפַּֽלְלוּ֙ וִֽיבַקְשׁ֣וּ פָנַ֔י

would be better understood as, *I will humble My people who (have the teaching of) calling My name by them. And they will pray and they will seek My face...etc.*

This means that for prayers to be efficacious and answered quickly and in the best possible way, proper form and intention matters. This idea is expressed by [Rabbi Yosef Gikatilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_ben_Abraham_Gikatilla) in his introduction to [Sefer Shaarei Orah](https://www.sefaria.org/Shaarei_Orah%2C_Introduction?lang=bi).

> **You asked me**, brother, dear friend, **to clarify in front of you a path about the names of the Holy One, Blessed be He, the Exalted and Almighty**, to produce with them according your will and to reach through them the object of your desire. And by seeing that your intention is honest, and better than (simply fulfilling) your request, I must let you know which way will spread light (be spiritually profitable); **namely, what is the way that HaShem Almighty desires or does not desire.** And when you get to know this, **then call HaShem and He will respond.** And you will be closest to him. And love Him with all your soul, and rejoice on HaShem. **And He will grant you the requests of your heart.**

In this case, the Hebrew word 'שמי' used in the expression from your quotation is understood as a Roshei Teivot for the names which form part of the inner intention (kavannah). It stands for the names of the 3 angels which are to be intended during traditional Jewish prayer.

The names of these three angels are Shmu-i-el (שמועיאל), Metatron (מטטרון) and Yehav-i-el (יהואל). These angels also correspond with the actual chain of prophetic transmission to the Jewish people, namely Shmuel HaNavi, Moshe Rabbeinu and Eliyahu HaNavi.

This is a tradition which has been passed down through the Prophets to the present day and which has its origins all the way back to Adam HaRishon.

For a detailed record of the chain of transmission and the mention of these three angelic names specifically, see this link to the [introduction to Sefer Brit Menucha](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44425&st=&pgnum=3) which is one of the authoritative sources discussing this subject.*(see also additional details on [Sefer Brit Menucha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berit_Menuchah) and its author [Rabbi Avraham ben Yitzchok of Granada/Rimon](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/abraham-ben-isaac-granada))*

This same teaching is echoed by [Isaiah the Prophet in 41:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.41.25?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> I have roused him from the north, and he has come, From the sunrise, one who invokes **My name**; And he has trampled rulers like mud, Like a potter treading clay.
>
> הַעִיר֤וֹתִי מִצָּפוֹן֙ וַיַּ֔את מִמִּזְרַח־שֶׁ֖מֶשׁ **יִקְרָ֣א בִשְׁמִ֑י** וְיָבֹ֤א סְגָנִים֙ כְּמוֹ־חֹ֔מֶר וּכְמ֥וֹ יוֹצֵ֖ר יִרְמָס־טִֽיט׃

And again in [Isaiah 43:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.43.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which repeats the concept:

> **כֹּ֚ל הַנִּקְרָ֣א בִשְׁמִ֔י** וְלִכְבוֹדִ֖י בְּרָאתִ֑יו יְצַרְתִּ֖יו אַף־עֲשִׂיתִֽיו׃

And also in [Zechariah the Prophet 13:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.13.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) who says:

> That third I will put into the fire, And I will smelt them as one smelts silver And test them as one tests gold. **He will call in My name**, And I will respond to him. I will declare, “You are My people,” And he will declare, “The L-RD is my G-d!”
>
> וְהֵבֵאתִ֤י אֶת־הַשְּׁלִשִׁית֙ בָּאֵ֔שׁ וּצְרַפְתִּים֙ כִּצְרֹ֣ף אֶת־הַכֶּ֔סֶף וּבְחַנְתִּ֖ים כִּבְחֹ֣ן אֶת־הַזָּהָ֑ב **ה֣וּא ׀** **יִקְרָ֣א בִשְׁמִ֗י וַֽאֲנִי֙ אֶעֱנֶ֣ה אֹת֔וֹ** אָמַ֙רְתִּי֙ עַמִּ֣י ה֔וּא וְה֥וּא יֹאמַ֖ר יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהָֽי׃

This third example from Zechariah is the most clear reference to the concept that it applies to prayer.

This idea is also expressed in [Sifrei to Devarim 49:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.49.1?vhe=Sifrei_Devarim,_Hebrew&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he). G-d wants us to pray with proper intention which includes intending the system by which He has created the entire universe *(meaning also intending the appropriate angelic names)*. But at the same time, it must be constantly remembered what is also expressed in the Sifrei just preceding this, namely [by Hillel at the end of 48:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.48.12?vhe=Sifrei_Devarim,_Hebrew&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he).

> And thus does Hillel say: "One who makes use of the 'Crown' (for his own purposes) passes away" (from the world.)

This is referring to someone who tries to appeal exclusively to the angelic influences, something called *binding names.* Even though we are taught to have these intentions, we know we only pray to G-d. These intentions are simply proper form and etiquette.

Regarding your last question, the name, Israel, has an element that alludes to a similar structure to that of angels. But like is taught in the Zohar, Israel transcends the concept of angels. This is expressed through the statement that Israel, the Torah and the Holy One, blessed be He are all one.

Comment: Interesting. I have a vague recollection of hearing this book "Sefer Brit Menucha" in a shul lecture by a visiting kabbalistic rabbi, who said, in certain situation, it is okay, to pronounce Hashem's Name (i.e. YHWH) as vowelised in the Tanakh. I just taugh that somehow this was the name in question.

Comment: I should note that, while I fully agree with Yaacov that "we know we only pray to G-d," it can be very hard to read that into some early kabbalistic sources (like R' Chaim Vital and sefer Yosher Levav). I discuss those in this essay: https://marbitz.com/home/rabbi-s-r-hirsch/finding-tradition-in-the-modern-torah-world/how-are-we-supposed-to-pray/

Comment: @dlanced Rabbi Chaim Vital is late in terms of kabbalistic teaching and did not diverge from what previous generations taught and accepted. You can rest assured that none of it diverged from the tradition that was given to us by Moshe Rabbeinu. With respect, the difficulty, if there is any, is only with your understanding of what he is saying.

Comment: @Yaacov. I'm not sure it's accurate to say that R' Chaim Vital "did not diverge from what previous generations taught and accepted" He actually wrote (in his introduction to Eitz Chaim) that you mustn't trust the contents of any of the kabbalistic books written after the Ramban:  והנה כל ספרי המקובלים האחרונים שהיו אחר הרמב"ן ז"ל אל תקרב אליהם כי מן הרמב"ן ואילך נסתרה דרך החכמה הזאת מעיני כל החכמים ולא נשאר בהם כי אם קצת ענפי הקדמות בלתי שרשיהם ועליהם בנו המקובלים האחרונים ז"ל דבריהם בשכל אנושי ומעצמך תוכל לדעת לעמוד על המבחן...

Comment: In that introduction, he also wrote that there was no unbroken direct transmission of at least key elements of his teachings, since he claimed that the Ari learned them through Eliyahu and NOT from this-worldly teachers: כ"ז היה מעצמו ע"י חסידותו ופרישותו אחרי התעסקו ימים ושנים רבים בספרים חדשים גם ישנים בחכמה הזאת ועליהם הוסיף חסידות ופרישות וטהרה וקדושה היא הביאתו לידי אליהו הנביא שהיה נגלה אליו תמיד ומדבר עמו פה אל פה ולמדו זאת החכמה

Comment: But most importantly, the Tzfas teachings are violently different in substance and style from anything the Ramban wrote. I would appreciate if you could point me to even a subtle hint to tzimtzum anywhere in Ramban.

Comment: @dlanced I'm very familiar with what Rabbi Vital writes in his introduction to Eitz Chaim and also the exceptions that he makes to that general statement particularly in Sha'ar Ruach HaKodesh based upon the explicit teaching he was given by the Ari z"l. You may not be sure, but I am. In fact, Sefer Brit Menucha is one of those books specifically mentioned as legitimate and reliable by the Ari z'l. The author is purported by many to actually be Chamau Gaon, who preceded Ramban. And Rabbi Vital does not exclude the 'yechidei segulah', who did continue the teachings.

Comment: @dlanced Concerning your 3rd comment, the Ari z'l and Rabbi Vital both continue the teaching  that is found with Rabbi Abraham Abulafia as is quoted verbatim in Sha'ar Ruach HaKodesh, section 4. What you term "violently different" is actually just the traditional path of the "Bnai HaNevi'im".  In our current generation, we are very fortunate in that many of these older traditions that were in very restricted manuscripts have actually been printed. If you have personal interest in this area, may you be blessed in going from strength to strength in its pursuit.

Comment: @dlanced Regarding the Abulafia reference, see his Sefer Chaye Olam HaBa. It shouldn't be forgotten that during his lifetime, many Gadolim were strongly opposed to his teachings being disseminated. And yet, this is precisely the path which the Ari z"l taught to Rabbi Chaim Vital. Rabbi Abulafia continued the same teaching associated with Ramban which is learning directly from Eliyahu HaNavi and others, just like Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato continued after the Ari z"l.

Comment: While you're correct that the approach of the Ramban wasn't the only one among the rishonim, tzimtzum was, at least in the context of existing writings of the rishonim, an innovation of the Ari (or, in his account, the product of supernatural revelation). No one I've seen claims there was a human mesorah. But none of this addresses the sources quoted in that essay that seem to advocate davening to partzufim: https://marbitz.com/home/rabbi-s-r-hirsch/finding-tradition-in-the-modern-torah-world/how-are-we-supposed-to-pray/

Comment: @dlanced If you are the author to the linked article in Marbitz by Rabbi Boruch (David B.) Clinton, the 2nd paragraph to that article says it all. Your understanding of the teachings of the Ari z”l and those who follow him (like for example the Vilna Gaon among countless others) is that they mistakenly are following a kind of idol worship and pray to some intellectual construct called “partzufim”. Your understanding and comprehension of kabbalistic teaching is incorrect. You need a personal teacher to learn this subject. There a many in the Toronto area you could take advantage of.

Comment: @Yaacov I'm afraid that's not how it works. If you feel I've made a specific mistake interpreting a specific passage, let me know (providing specific, sourced evidence). I'm genuinely eager to hear and I'll listen seriously to all advice. But just throwing out broad and vague generalisations isn't helpful. As I'm sure you'll agree: for us Jews, it's all about sources.

Comment: @dlanced If I understand your 1st comment, your primary question relates not to my answer, but to your article which makes the statement that in your opinion, the kabbalists from the time of the Acharonim who primarily follow the teachings of the Ari z”l are praying not to HaKadosh, Baruch Hu, but the intellectual construct of partzufim and that this is a departure from the kabbalistic teaching of the Rishonim. So for example, when Rabbi Abulafia in Sefer Pardes HaSefar discusses partzufim (briefly) what do you make of that? And that is only one example.

Comment: @dlanced I’m not sure what you mean when referencing tzimtzum as being a chiddush. Nomenclature changes from one style of teaching to the next, but the underlying concepts remain. The same sort of variety exists within Chassidic teaching which often uses completely different nomenclature.

Comment: @dlanced And just to point out in my answer, my kabbalistic sources are from Rishonim and the prophets,not Acharonim. So your personal bias against those from the Acharonim aren’t relevant to my answer anyway.

Comment: @Yaacov. That's all very reasonable. Indeed, my concerns are only with the influence of the Tzfas school. Although from what I understand (third-hand) about Abulafia, whatever he meant by partzufim would not match the Ari's approach. Abulafia was even fiercely opposed to sefiros.

Comment: @dlanced That last assumption is also incorrect. Abulafia teaches like things are taught in Sefer Yetzirah, Maayan HaChochmah, Sefer Raziel and elsewhere. Like I said previously, if you are truly interested in learning this part of the Torah, you have many people in the Toronto area you could turn to. Bracha v'hatzlacha.

Answer (score 1):

```
     יְבָרֶכְךָ֥ יְהוָ֖ה וְיִשְׁמְרֶֽךָ׃  

  יָאֵ֨ר יְהוָ֧ה׀ פָּנָ֛יו אֵלֶ֖יךָ וִֽיחֻנֶּֽךָּ׃  ס

  יִשָּׂ֨א יְהוָ֤ה׀ פָּנָיו֙ אֵלֶ֔יךָ וְיָשֵׂ֥ם לְךָ֖ שָׁלֽוֹם׃  ס

     וְשָׂמ֥וּ אֶת־שְׁמִ֖י עַל־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל וַאֲנִ֖י אֲבָרֲכֵֽם׃
```

במדבר 6: 24–27

כִּ֤י עַתָּה֙ שָׁלַ֣חְתִּי אֶת־יָדִ֔י וָאַ֥ךְ אוֹתְךָ֛ וְאֶֽת־עַמְּךָ֖ בַּדָּ֑בֶר וַתִּכָּחֵ֖ד מִן־הָאָֽרֶץ׃

```
  וְאוּלָ֗ם בַּעֲב֥וּר זֹאת֙ הֶעֱמַדְתִּ֔יךָ בַּעֲב֖וּר הַרְאֹתְךָ֣ אֶת־כֹּחִ֑י
```

16–15:9 ואלה שמות

וַיֹּ֨אמֶר מֹשֶׁ֜ה אֶל־הָֽאֱלֹהִ֗ים הִנֵּ֨ה אָנֹכִ֣י בָא֮ אֶל־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵל֒ וְאָמַרְתִּ֣י לָהֶ֔ם אֱלֹהֵ֥י אֲבוֹתֵיכֶ֖ם שְׁלָחַ֣נִי אֲלֵיכֶ֑ם וְאָֽמְרוּ־לִ֣י מַה־שְּׁמֹ֔ו מָ֥ה אֹמַ֖ר אֲלֵהֶֽם׃

```
  וַיֹּ֤אמֶר אֱלֹהִים֙ אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֔ה אֶֽהְיֶ֖ה אֲשֶׁ֣ר אֶֽהְיֶ֑ה וַיֹּ֗אמֶר כֹּ֤ה תֹאמַר֙ לִבְנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל אֶֽהְיֶ֖ה שְׁלָחַ֥נִי אֲלֵיכֶֽם׃
```

14–13:3 ואלה שמות

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting and apparently good rendering of a similar expression, in Daniel 9:19 here:

https://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.9.19?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en

אֲדֹנָ֤י ׀ שְׁמָ֙עָה֙ אֲדֹנָ֣י ׀ סְלָ֔חָה אֲדֹנָ֛י הַֽקֲשִׁ֥יבָה וַעֲשֵׂ֖ה אַל־תְּאַחַ֑ר לְמַֽעֲנְךָ֣ אֱלֹהַ֔י כִּֽי־**שִׁמְךָ֣ נִקְרָ֔א עַל־עִירְךָ֖ וְעַל־עַמֶּֽךָ**׃

O Lord, hear! O Lord, forgive! O Lord, listen, and act without delay for Your own sake, O my God; **for Your name is attached to Your city and Your people**

Now Metzudat David says there:

כי שמך וכו׳. לומר עיר אלהים וכן אלהי ישראל ואין זו כבודך לעזבם ביד העכו״ם:

Translation: For Your name "is called" [meaning that that's what people say] "Ir Elohim" and "Elohei **Yisrael**." It would be against Your Honor to relinquish **these titles** to the idolaters/gentile nations!

---

Therefore in the context of your verse from 2 Chron 7, **it seems the name is a reference to "Elohei Yisrael" - meaning that His name (i.e. H' and/or Elkym) is attached to ours in this title** - especially since this verse is Hashem's response to Shelomo, and in the preceding chapter, in Shelomo's blessing and prayer, Shelomo says six times "H' Elohei Yisrael." Because the commentators don't say much/anything.

Also BTW Jastrow has an entry for קרה (קרא) - *join*, to which he also traces the word קריה - *town, settlement.* -- which is related to the statement and concept **"His Name is joined/partnered to ours"** -- in particular the name **Yisrael** as supported here:

from [Beit Aharon](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Aharon%2C_Teachings_on_Torah_and_Holidays%2C_R%27_Aharon_(the_Second)_of_Karlin%2C_Leviticus%2C_Kedoshim.14?vhe=Beit_Aharon,_Brody,_1875.&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

[P. Avot] opens and he said, All Yisrael "YS"/they have/there is/ - CLK-piece to the Coming World as it says And your people [will be] all tzaddikim etc.
He said: ****This name Yisrael is m'shutaf/joined/partnered with His Blessed Name**** as it's written **"And Thy Name is partnered with our name**." "They have a piece to the Coming World - meaning the aspect Y"S - is for them the piece to OHB, that HKBH created the world YeSh from AYN so too **Yisrael** need to [do the reflection] and make AYN from YeSh [looking to the Supernal and the Patriarchs and Tzaddikim etc etc] ...

פתח ואמר כל ישראל יש להם חלק לעוה"ב שנאמר ועמך כולם צדיקים כו'. אמר. **שם זה של ישראל משותף בשמו יתברך כמ"ש ושמך משותף בשמינו.** י"ש להם חלק לעולם הבא. היינו הבחינת י"ש הוא להם חלק לעוה"ב שהקב"ה ברא את העולם י"ש מאי"ן וישראל צריכין לעשות מהי"ש אי"ן. אשא עיני אל ההרים מאי"ן יבא עזרי. ההרים הם האבות כידוע. אשא עיני אל בחינת האבות. מאי"ן יבא עזרי מבחינת אי"ן יבא עזרי. ודקדק מהו לשון חלק הלא כל העוה"ב הוא שלהם. אלא החלק הוא גם בעוה"ז. כי צדיקים יש להם גם בעוה"ז חלק מה מעוה"ב. כי בכל תענוגי עוה"ז ועניניהם הם מרגישים חיות אלקות אעפ"י שעוה"ז ועוה"ב הם שני הפכים. כי העוה"ז מגושם בתכלית והעוה"ב הוא בתכלית הרוחניות. עכ"ז יכולים לטעום בעוה"ז טעם עוה"ב ע"י שמרגישין בכל דבר חיות אלקות. והזכיר בשם צדיק אחד פי' הפסוק טעמו וראו כי טוב י"י. היינו כי כל הטוב והתענוג והמתיקות של כל דבר עוה"ז הוא י"י כי הוא נמשך מהחיות אלקות שיש בכל דבר והוא החלק עוה"ב שצריך להרגיל עצמו לטעום בזה העולם:

---

And no **Yisrael is not a name of H"Y** but however there is a grand Chaya in heaven as we know from the [Baraita of R' Akiba](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%20%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%AA%20%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A2%20%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance)

One Chaya stands in RKYA and its name is **Yisrael** and inscribed on its forehead is "**Yisrael**." It stands in the middle of the RKIA and says: Barekhu et-H' the Blessed. And all the Supernal Allies reply: Blessed is H' forever and ever.

אמר רבי עקיבא: חיה אחת עומדת ברקיע, ושמה ישראל, וחקוק על מצחה ישראל, עומדת באמצע הרקיע ואומרת: ברכו את ה' המבורך; וכל גדודי מעלה עונים ואומרים: ברוך ברוך ה' המבורך לעולם ועד.

Also there is a chief supernal Sabba, the Sabba d'Sabbin, called **Yisrael** Sabba.

The point being these are reflections and chief archangels that are a charged over or are the root soul, respectively, of the nation below. **And they are called Yisrael, not Yehudah.**

---

I just received an anonymous msg: Yehosef will not submit to Judah's imperialism. Od Yosef Chai. Od Avi Chai. Avi Yisrael.

There is no higher name.